# Vuejs preserve element attributes

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-directives

My case looks like this:

Laravel template:

```
<div class="block-id" is="Header">
    <span>ID #3265872</span>
    <ul class="tools">
        <li><a href="{{ route('history') }}">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('top') }}">TOP</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button>Check</button>
</div>
```

The vuejs component looks just the same

```
<template>
    <div class="block-id">
        <span>ID #{{ids.id}}</span>
        <ul class="tools">
            <li><a>History</a></li>
            <li><a>TOP</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button>Check</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: "Header",
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('global', [
                'ids'
            ])
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that when I render the component the href attribute is gone. So is there any way to preserve the href attribute in a element?

Comment: What do you mean the href is gone? There is no href in the VueJS component?

Comment: Does not make sense. There's no `href` in `<li><a>History</a></li>`. There should be one?

Comment: Yes I know there is not href in vue template but there is one in laravel template. So is there any way to preserve the one in laravel tempalte when rendering vue template on a top of it?